# Calculate the number of lines of multiple files , using Fork() , where each child runs solo

Tags: c, linux, fork

Following my previous question [here][1] , I now want to calculate the number of lines of multiple files , where to each file I want to place a process ,a child process for that matter , that will run the method `calculateLines` for his own file , and find the number of lines of its file .

I wrote `fork()` as a system call (called `my_fork()`) , and here is the code :

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

     typedef struct fileChild {
       pid_t processID;
       char *fileName;
       int processFileLines;
     }  child;


     child children[argc];        // array of children

     int n = 0;   // using this to tell how much lines in a single file
     int i = 0;   // using this to iterate the number of files
     char dig;    // using this to convert into char the number of lines

     while (i < argc )
     {
         children[i].processID = my_fork();  // create process 'i' for file 'i'
         children[i].fileName = argv[i];
         children[i].processFileLines = calculateLines(children[i].fileName);
     }

     ....
     ....

     return 0;
 }
```

My question: is this how the subprocess can check the number of lines of his file (file `i` ) ?
I can't see how this (forking) improves my code ... please go easy on me , this is the first time that I work with processes .

**FINAL EDITION:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

 typedef unsigned int size_t;
 typedef signed ssize_t;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {



     char myArray[15];


     int n = 0;
     int i = 0;
     pid_t pid;


     for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
     {

         if ((pid = my_fork()) == 0)

         {
             n = calculateLines(argv[i]);
             sprintf (myArray, "\nfile%d: %d \n", i,n);
             my_write(1,myArray,15);

         }
        else if (pid < 0)
            break;

     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Testing in terminal :

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./ProjOsFInal somefile.txt about.html epl-v10.html
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ 
file2: 300 

file1: 133 

file3: 327 

file2: 300 

file3: 327 

file3: 327 

file3: 327
```

Comment: Note that you should reset `i = 1;` rather than `i = 0;` before the final loop.  You could usefully use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop at the end.  You also have `int i = 0;` at the top, followed immediately by `i = 1;`, which is a tad wasteful (though the compiler will probably optimize that away for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify the code a bit.  One problem you have is that you are currently processing `argv[0]`, which is the name of the program rather than of any of its arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t kids[argc];   // VLA
    int n_kids = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        pid_t pid;
        if ((pid = my_fork()) == 0)
        {
            be_childish(argv[i]);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid < 0)
            break;
        else
            kids[n_kids++] = pid;
    }
    int status;
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) > 0)
        n_kids = note_death_of_child(pid, status, n_kids, kids);
    return(0);
}
```

The `note_death_of_child()` function simply finds the entry in the list.  Actually, you really don't need the list of children here, but you could note as each child exits, and what its exit status is.

The `be_childish()` function is given the name of a file.  It opens the file, reads it, closes it, writes whatever needs to be written, and exits.  The call to `exit()` in the loop of the `main()` function is there as a defence mechanism against mis-implemented childish functions.

Comment: Okay thanks , can you please see my edited post ? something is still no right with the code . From some reason I get some Gibrish .

Comment: There are a couple of problems: (1) your new code doesn't wait for the children to finish before trying to do the post-processing, and (2) your children modify their own local variables, but cannot affect the parent process's variables.  You'll need some other mechanism to get the information from the children back to the parent process; pipes and shared memory are two possibilities.

Comment: I didn't "learn" pipes yet ,then I can't use it . What do you mean by shared memory?

Comment: If you didn't learn shared memory or pipes, then you are rather limited in your choices for IPC (interprocess communications), then you need to stop having the parent try to replicate the printing that the children do.

Comment: Also, remember that reading a manual page is permitted, and may even be creditworthy. The system calls are [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), and either the System V shared memory primitives ([`shmat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) et al) or the POSIX shared memory primitives ([`shm_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) et al). In many circumstances, you'd need to know about synchronization for access to shared memory; this isn't one, provided you wait for the kids.

Comment: Final changes were made , but I still have one problem : the lines are repeating . Can you please give me a feedback  ? the changes are above , thanks !

Comment: Your child processing isn't exiting when it's done, so the first child goes back and runs the next iteration (as well as the parent), and so on.  You weren't paying attention to my outline code; that carefully deals with exactly this problem.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is edited to reflect your revision and form change

fork() returns the process ID of the child it creates, or 0 if it is the created child. So if you can use this to distinguish if you're the parent, which needs to fork more, or the child, which should get busy counting lines.

If I understand you correctly, you'd want to fork after setting local variables such as fileName. Here's a simplified example:

```
const char *local_filename;
pid_t f;
int i = 0;
while (i < argc) {
  i++;
  local_filename = argv[i];
  f =  my_fork();
  if (f == 0) { // fork() returns 0 if we are a child, so we want to be a child prcess here
    calculate stuff;
    ...
    break; // Since we're a child we don't want to go on and spawn more, so we exit the loop and are done
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd want to fork for each process , meaning the only reason for forking , would be to count lines of another file .BTW I lost you with "if (f == 0) break;" , why break ? it would mean that I'll stop to count , where there are more files to count ...

Comment: fork() returns 0 when it is a child process. only the parent process should keep spawning, the parent process will have 0 returned. a child process should exit the loop it is in and start working on counting, that is why we break when we receive notification that we are a child

Comment: sorry, I meant the parent process will get something OTHER THAN 0 returned

Comment: I've edited my post , can you please explain me why I get the Gibrish in addition to the line "file1:2" ?  thank you !

Comment: Initial look looks like you're not incrementing i *before* the fork in the loop. in a for loop it increments it right at the end: so this is spawning the correct # of processes, it is just doing it too many times. incrementing i should be the first thing you do in the loop. I'll update my answer to reflect that. also if you do it this way there's no need to use (if pid < 0)

Comment: oh also it might be that you dont break; when the child is done, letting you fork() again before testing the pid. this gives you another valid child process (of your child process). the reason it doesn't get stopped is because you test for (pid < 0) when it should be (pid == 0)

Comment: @ron I'm sorry, I caused confusion. I like to browse SO in the morning and I'm rusty with fork(). I cleared it up and I hope this 100% answers your question now, sorry for the confusion I've caused!